# How to disable key-tap sound in android?

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I want to enable/disable key-tap sound in android version higher then 4.2. There are any way to change default setting through programming.
 Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mute the sound when your app starts and unmute when it finishes using `AudioManager`

```
@override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // this mute the Sound
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
}

@override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways
 1) In XML by setting tag `android:soundEffectsEnabled` true or false 
2) In Activity by pragmatically `setSoundEffectsEnabled(true/false).`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. There is an attribute and a method if you want to enable/disable.

> android:soundEffectsEnabled
>
> Boolean that controls whether a view should have sound effects enabled for events such as clicking and touching.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:soundEffectsEnabled) you go.

No need for audio manager or muting for sound stream of system.